# print() issue in R. Using RStudio. row.names is not working

Tags: r, printing

```
print(paste("hello",d<-1),row.names=FALSE) 

//Output
[1] "hello 1"
```

Why is row.names not working here?

Shouldn't the [1] be supressed?

Please help.

Comment: In which documentation of the function `print()` you read that the function takes an argument `row.names=FALSE` ?

Comment: @jogo - The `print.data.frame()` method has the argument.  But obviously, it does not apply here since the result from `paste()` is not a data frame.

Answer (score 1):

The function `print` doesn't include any `row.names` argument. If you want a simple output without the `[1]` you can use `cat`, and then you don't even have to use `paste`:

```
cat("hello", 1)
```

Comment: @Richard gave the right comment: `print.data.frame()` knows the parameter for printing dataframes.

Comment: Thanks a bunch everyone. I am an absolute newbie to R and (embarrassingly, obviously) don't know my way around R documentation, even though I did try there first. Thanks again for clearing up my confusion. I was trying to use cat but it wouldn't output lists. So I was forced to use print(). Is there any way to parse out the line numbers out of the print() output, like using sub strings or something? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

like jogo said, I can't find any documentation on`row.names` being an argument for `print()`. But you can just use `cat()`:

```
cat(paste("hello",d<-1))
```